# Question about selecting form children jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Again I'm asking question about comment form, I'm making an image website and every image has its own comment form, so when I submit form I do like this :

```
$('#comment_form').live('submit', function() {
 ...
```

So in order to select only this form textearea value I tried using this but I get undefined error here is how I tried :

```
$('#comment_form').live('submit', function() {
 image_comment_text=$(this).closest("#comment_text").val(); //textarea id is comment_text
```

I tried to used find(), its working but when I submit comments for few images I get comments 2 or 3 times as I should, because find finds all occurrences of textarea with comment_text id .. how can I do this ?

@molf , here is HTML generated by javascript:

```
var xHTML = "<div class=\"addComment\">";
   xHTML += "<form action=\"<?=base_url()?>images/post_comment/" + post + "\" method=\"post\" class=\"comment_form\" name=\"comment_form\">";
   xHTML += "<input type=\"hidden\" class=\"comment_post_id\" name=\"comment_post_id\" value=\"" +post + "\"/>"; 
   xHTML += "<textarea class=\"comment\" name=\"comment_text\" rows=\"8\" cols=\"40\"></textarea>";
      xHTML += "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" class=\"post_image_comment\" value=\"Comment\"><span> Don't make it too big!</span>";
   xHTML += "</form></div>";
```

**EDIT**

When I print to console log the value of textarea I get only one result as I should, now when I try to append the ul comments I get 2 of the same values .. here how it goes ..

```
<ul class="comments"></ul>
```

below is the comment form which is not in the document at all, when certain anchor is clicked the form pops out below `.comments` , when form submits I want to append the comments to add the new comment to list items of existing unordered list comments , here is the whole code :

```
$('form[name^="comment_form"]').live('submit', function(event) {
  r= $(this).find('> .comment').val();

                $('<div class="overlay"></div>')
    .appendTo('.addComment')
             .fadeIn(200, function() {
          $('.comments')
             .append('<li id="new_append">' + r + '</li>')
              .children(':last')
           .height($('.comments li:last').height())
           .hide()
           .slideDown(800, function() { 
             var bodyHeight = $('html').height();
            $('.addComment').fadeOut(500, function() {
              $('html').height(bodyHeight);
           $('h2#leaveAComment').fadeOut(200, function(){$(this).text('Thank you for your comment!').fadeIn(200)});
          });
         });  
        $('html, body').scrollTo( $('#new_append'), 800 );
        });
    event.preventDefault();
            });
```

**EDIT II** @patrick

The javascript which loads the comment form is above .. here is HTML :

-------------BEGIN FOR EACH--------------

```
<div id="image-12" class="image_content">
<img src="..." />
 <ul class="comments hidden"> //This is where the comments are appended to <li></li>

 </ul>

<div style="float: left; display: block; width: 100%;">
<a id="image_comment-12" class="image_comment" onclick="showComments('12');" href="javascript:;">Add Comment</a>
</div>

  <div id="addComment-12">//this is where the comment form loads

  </div>

</div>
```

----------END--- FOR EACH--------- image ...

Comment: `closest` finds closest *parent* of an element. I.e. it searches back from your form up to `html` element, not within your form.

Comment: @vava how can I search within, but to apply to only one element with certain class

Comment: @c0mrade, molf gave you correct answer, use `:first` (or `:last`) modifier on your query.

Comment: @vava again the same thing I get multiple selected values

Comment: If you add an alert(image_comment_text) to your event, how many times do you see it?

Comment: @CResults, this is the major issue, I load first comment submit it, then only one comment is posted, I load second comment form submit it, then two comments are posted, this one two times, I do it for third comment form , submit 3 comments and load n forms submit n comments meaning that find() function finds all occurrences of comment_text

Comment: @c0mrade I it almost sounds like your forms are getting nested. Are you sure your `append` code is adding it in the right place? Also, your `input` for the submit is missing a self closing slash: `/>`

Comment: @c0mrade did you see my edited answer below?

Comment: @CResults yes I did, I'm not sure what you think cofused .. 
@Doug Neiner it isn't adding at the right place, but I'd like to get it working, 1 thing at a time, now I'm concerned why it is doubling tripling the added comments

Comment: This isn't your issue, but reading your code, is this line correct? `r= $(this).find('> .comment').val();` I don't see any element with a class named `comment` in your dynamically added form.

Comment: @patrick , sorry I changed comment_text to comment , I edited question as well

Comment: I assume `.appendTo('.addComment')` and `('#addComment').fadeOut(...` are indeed two different 'addComment' elements?

Comment: This line: `.append('<li id="new_append">' + r + '</li>')` Should `new_append` be a class, or will it only be created once?

Comment: Ok, yes, I am confused. Here is how I have it

1. You display a page with, usually, 25 pictures
2. Under each picture is a comment button
3. If a comment button is pressed, you dymically load a comment form
4. User populates comment form and submits
5. First time this happens you get the expected one result.

Now this is where I get confused. If I as the user pressed the same comment button again under the same picture would you dynamically load the same HTML comment form?

Comment: @CResults you got everything right , let me clearify this one : "If I as the user pressed the same comment button again under the same picture would you dynamically load the same HTML comment form?" user presses another comment button and another form pops out..

Comment: @patrcik I edited the question, .addComment is the right form, I fixed a lot based on your and others suggestions, the new_append is created many times, but when I set it to class instead of id, when I press submit button, its prints out `<li>comment</li>` indefinitely many times so I have to reload to make it stop

Comment: Using an ID multiple times is not a proper fix. Could you please add the code that inserts the dynamic form? Also, a shortened version of the HTML that houses the list of photos?

Comment: The js that loads the comment form is where? I see where the xHTML string is constructed, but I don't see where/how it is loaded into the DOM.

Comment: @patrick its inside a function showComments(), it loads comment form just the below the button add a comment, the function is on the same page generating form on click

Comment: @patrick, maybe I'm doing this whole thing wrong, I'm trying to do exactly the same comments as here on SO, how did they do this, maybe I'll do it with some animations and stuff, but this simple comments appeal to me ..

Comment: @c0mrade OK I'm still confused (and prob why this isn't working). By pressing submit, unless you are using AJAX your page must refresh totally and on refresh be without a comments textbox. HOW at this point does pressing submit give you more than one comment?

Comment: @CResults Ok imagine this, imagine instead of answers here on SO, you had some images, instead of every answer there is image, now you want to comment on some of images, you comment on one, you click the Add Comment, textearea pops out .. and you add your comment.. and you can add as many comments as you like on many images/answers(SO) without page refresh. better?

Comment: @c0mrade. Yep, I get that, I get the idea perfectly. But as I understand it, when your page loads it loads without any textareas. If the user then clicks the add comment button/link some javascript fires which adds a textarea for them to add comments. It adds one textarea, the user fills the box and presses submit. Your page then refreshes again, again without any textareas on the page. Unless the user presses another one of the add comments buttons, you should only get one comment submitted...

Comment: @CResult, the comments submission works perfectly, just something is wrong with appending them, for some reason , when I post 2 or more comments on different images I get the same comments on both of them ..

Comment: The reason I wanted to see your code that is inserting the forms, is that when you submit, you are getting an infinite loop. Makes me think that the forms are somehow nested inside each other. Or when you insert the form, it is being inserted for each photo instead of just the desired one. Or some other insertion issue.

Comment: thank you guys, I'll not close this question, I'll try to build something more simple from scratch, this has become over complicated

Comment: No problem @c0mrade. I think your current solution isn't that hard/tricky but because @patrick and I can only see half of your code, helping to debug it is hard work. If you are able to host what you have so far so we can see it in action we may well be able to solve it for you.

Comment: I have it on the localhost , nothing online..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, change your selector for your form. I think you can select form by name using the id selector, but you're not supposed to duplicate ids on a page, so jQuery live is probably only watching the first form. This is just a guess, though.

Also, it doesn't matter what class/id you use for your textarea.  If you're only going to have one textarea per form, you can use the `:text` selector.  When finding children, I like to use the children selector.

```
$('form[name="comment_form"]').live('submit', function() {
  image_comment_text = $(this).find('> :text').val();
});
```

If you're using name instead of id because you're going to have multiple forms, I would suggest changing the name to comment_form_'image_id', then your selector would be: `$('form[name^="comment_form"]')`
Notice the `^` which requires the name to start with 'comment_form'.  That way, you can have unique form names (comment_form_234, comment_form_235) and still have the desired effect.

Edit:

I looked at your code update, and it looks to me like you're ignoring the context of the current form in your function.  For instance, when you use the selector `$('.comments').append(...` you're appending to all elements on your page which match that selector.  In order to retrieve the proper elements, you'll have to always use your selector as `$(this).find(' > .comments').append(...` which will work within the context of the submitted form.

I took a few minutes to edit your code, I haven't run it or anything, but it should be close to what you're trying to do.  I hope it at least gets you started in the right direction:

```
$('form[name^="comment_form"]').live('submit', function (event) {
    r = $(this).find('> .comment').val();
    /* get addComment-classed element */
    var addComment = $(this).find(' > .addComment:first');

    /* get comments-classed element */
    var comments = $(this).find(' > .comments:first');

    $('<div class="overlay"></div>').appendTo(addComment).fadeIn(200, function () {
        /* note comments element, not selector */
        $(comments).append('<li id="new_append">' + r + '</li>').children(':last').height(
        /* again, element */
        $(comments).find(' > li:last').height()).hide().slideDown(800, function () {
            var bodyHeight = $('html').height();

            /* again, element */
            $(addComment).fadeOut(500, function () {
                $('html').height(bodyHeight);
                $('h2#leaveAComment').fadeOut(200, function () {
                    $(this).text('Thank you for your comment!').fadeIn(200)
                });
            });
        });
        $('html, body').scrollTo($('#new_append'), 800);
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I added comments in the code, but notice that the addComments and comments selectors are 'cached'.  If you're going to be accessing these elements multiple times, storing them in a variable before using them will cut back on DOM traversals.  This should really solve your comments being added to multiple elements on your page.

Comment: @Jim Schubert thank you jim for your answer .. when I use your selector I get undefined to my console log .. how ever I like your approach with for name

Comment: @Jim Schubert r= $(this).find('> :text').val(); this is undefined, when I changed it to r= $(this).find('> .comment').val(); its working but there is something wrong again still getting the double value , I edited my question btw

Comment: @c0mrade I don't think you can return false for form submit.  try changing `$('selector').live('submit', function() {` to `$('selector').live('submit', function(event) {` and at the end of the function, replace return false with `event.preventDefault();`  But, you'll have to handle your form submit on the server side using $.post or $.ajax within your function, otherwise comments only exist per page view.

Comment: @Jim Schubert thank you I did that, I'm no so worried about ajax at this moment, I'm more worried is why do I get multiple comments appended when I select only one, I edited question maybe you could take a look at the code, something is obviously wrong ..

Comment: @c0mrade I updated my answer with some code that I think you'll find helpful.  If you prefer, you can use `$(this).find('.comments:first-child')`, but I personally like the `>` because it visually suggests the element's location.  Also, I've used element throughout, but I believe `:first` returns a jQuery object.  The actual html element can be cached with, for instance, `$(this).find(' > .comments:first').get(0)`

Answer (score 1):

First, the find() method was the correct way to go if used within the proper context.

Second, it sounds like you are re-using IDs. This is not allowed. An ID can be used only once on a page.

The closest() function searches 'up' from (and including) the DOM element. The find() function searches the content of the element.

EDIT:

I assume the form is being submitted when the user clicks the submit button. I also assume that there's more to your `submit()` handler than is shown. Is that correct?

Sometimes you need to add `$(this).preventDefault();` in order to keep the form from being submitted in your code, as well as by the default behavior of the 'submit' button.

The following does the same thing (essentially) as find(). It will find the item with the .comment_text class within the form being submitted. So it should only grab the value of one item:

`image_comment_text=$(".comment_text", this).val();`

Comment: @patrick that is true I'm planning to do that, replace ids with class, but at the end I get the same thing juqery selects class and ID all the same

Comment: Multiple IDs will confuse things. It should never be done as it will cause things to behave unexpectedly.

Comment: @c0mrade - Perhaps the form is being submitted multiple times? Try `$(this).preventDefault();`. (see edits)

Comment: @patrick I edited my question, I used that what you suggested its working as the suggestions from the other people .. but something with my append may be wrong ..

Answer (score 1):

How many `comment_form`s do you have on a each page? For correct HTML you should only have one id='comment_text' and one id='comment_form' per page.

Consider changing your ids to class='comment_text' and finding with .comment_text rather than #comment_text

---

I think from your latest comments the issue may be the way you are dynamically adding your form/comments textbox to the page.

Once you've entered comments and submitted them do you then remove the form you've dynamically added? I would recommend this as if not I think your DOM structure is getting confused causing the problems you are experiencing.

Comment: I have an image search which enables users to choose how many results they want per page, I'd say 25 by default, I will do that.. swithc from ID to class but I'd like to get this working ..

Answer (score 0):

You are getting duplicate comments because you aren't removing the previous add comment form. Try adding this to the end of your `.slideDown` callback function:

```
$(this).remove();
```

Here is the full submit function, I made a few changes/additions:

- I removed the `>` from the `find('.comment')` as it isn't necessary
- Changed the new append to a class, then removed it after you scroll to it.
- Removed the form when complete
- Changed the `event.preventDefault();` to `return false;`... this is more of a personal preference than anything.

I hope this helps :)

```
 $('form[name^="comment_form"]').live('submit', function(event) {
  r = $(this).find('.comment').val();
  $('<div class="overlay"></div>')
   .appendTo('.addComment')
   .fadeIn(200, function() {
    $('.comments')
     .append('<li class="new_append">' + r + '</li>')
     .children(':last')
     .height($('.comments li:last').height())
     .hide()
     .slideDown(800, function() {
      var bodyHeight = $('html').height();
      $('.addComment').fadeOut(500, function() {
       $('html').height(bodyHeight);
       $('h2#leaveAComment').fadeOut(200, function(){$(this).text('Thank you for your comment!').fadeIn(200)});
       $(this).remove();
      });
     });
     $('html, body').scrollTo( $('.new_append:last'), 800 );
     $('.new_append').removeClass('new_append');
   });
  return false;
 });
```